# Is there a way to make buffer() writable without copying when the size argument is set?

Tags: python, linux, security, python-2.x, 32-bit

If an object is mutable then it’s possible to get a modifiable buffer by not the specifying the second argument of `buffer()` *(which is a built‑in function)* like this :

```
>>> s = bytearray(1000000)   # a million zeroed bytes
>>> t = buffer(s, 1)         # slice cuts off the first byte
>>> s[1] = 5                 # set the second element in s
>>> t[0]                     # which is now also the first element in t!
'\x05'
```

However, in my case, I need to specify`0x7fffffff`as the size parameter. In that case :

```
>>> b = buffer(bytearray('a'), 1,0x7fffffff)
```

[how to make `b` writeable without copying it’s data](https://bugs.python.org/issue21831) ? In my case`_ctypes`support is disabled and the program isn’t launched as root.
Of course, thing like memoryview are available, but I loose the possibility to read the memory at every virtual addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The copy is necessary. The bytearray's internal buffer simply isn't 2 GiB long; if you want a 2 GiB buffer, you will need to copy the bytearray's data into a new buffer.

If you were to somehow force Python to treat the buffer as the size you want it to be without making a copy, writing to it would corrupt your process's memory and/or cause a segfault.

Comment: Did you pay attention to the security tag. I forgot to [include this](https://bugs.python.org/issue21831 "they use version of python which is vulnerable") in my question. I gained the possibility to execute arbitrary python code on a web site. But their bounty program will only reward if I escape the sandbox used for the interpreter *(I need execute native assembly code for this)*.

Comment: `writing to it would corrupt your process's memory`. This is what I want to do : I need to access system calls directly for being able to escape the os level sandbox. This require being able to execute native assembly so I can bypass the python level sandbox *(the python sandbox prevent me from escaping the ᴏꜱ‑level sandbox)*.

Comment: @user2284570: Well, if you're trying to exploit that bug, you run into the additional problem that buffer objects created with `buffer` just aren't writeable at all, whether or not you pass a size argument, and there's no Python-side API to make them writeable. You made a write through the bytearray with `s[1] = 5`, not a write through the buffer object.

Comment: If you want to take over a Python process, I'd look into other approaches. There are plenty of other attack vectors, such as constructing your own Python code object that writes past the end of its locals array, or seeing if they forgot to disable `_ctypes`, or just using something like the `os.exec*` functions, or taking advantage of a reference leak (maybe the one in `property.__init__`) to overflow an object's refcount, deallocate it, and use the dangling reference to screw with the internals of something that gets allocated over the same space.

Comment: I already in my question told`_ctype`isn’t available due to the python level sandbox. Everything that can be used to launch an external app is removed *(things like `os.popen()` or `os.system()` or `os.fork()` are disabled)*. Even`_socket`don’t exists. It’s also impossible to write to files *(the python sandbox ensure everything is read‑only)*.  Most of the python standard library is available. It’s just function that could harm the system are disabled.

Comment: @user2284570: You only said `ctypes`, not `_ctypes`. Did they go so far as to compile a custom build of Python to knock out things like `posix.execve` and prevent it from coming back on `reload(posix)`? Unlike most of the other things mentioned so far, that one can't be taken out by deleting a file somewhere in a release build.

Comment: `import ctypes`yield a backtrace telling the _ctypes modules don’t exists. `Did they go so far as to compile a custom build of Python` No they didn’t, the python sandbox is written in python and every line of code or python bytecode is instrumented through it *(the python sandbox being custom I have no way to know how it works)*. But yes, things like`posix.execve`or`reload(posix)`don’t work. For things like `_ctypes`, I think they just removed the shared object file in the`lib-dynload`folder which is found in the python library directory *(the place where you can find os.py or ssl.py)*.